# ADODB.Stream read bytes in chunks

Tags: windows, adodb

The following codes work, but instead of oStream.Read which reads all bytes at once,
I want to read it in chunks...what is the api for it? I see there is something "oStream.Read 256"
that allows you to read the first 256 bytes, but that is not what I need...

say the file is 1,000,000 bytes, I want to read it 256 bytes at a time...
0-255, 256-511 so on...

```
oStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
oStream.Type = adTypeBinary;
oStream.Open;
oStream.LoadFromFile(oItem.path);
content = oStream.Read;
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just made a test script using your code and as long as I define `adTypeBinary` as `1`, substitute `oItem.path` for a known filename and use oStream.Read(256), it works as you require. Check to see it you aren't accidentally reloading the file or rewinding the stream. If all else fails, the `Position` property should be able to set the next read position for you.